# AJAX file upload aborted with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout, multipartform-data

I try to build an upload script with Code Igniter and jQuery. On my laptop, everything works fine, but when I upload the script on my web servers, the upload process is aborted instantaneously if the file is bigger than 2kb. I thought it was a server config problem, so I wrote the following script which allow to test the AJAX and the HTML way. The result is that it's ok in HTML and it craches in AJAX :

**upload.php** :

```
<?php


if( count($_FILES) )
{
    $content_dir = './';

    $tmp_file = $_FILES['fichier']['tmp_name'];

    if( !is_uploaded_file($tmp_file) )
    {
        die("File not found");
    }

    $name_file = $_FILES['fichier']['name'];

    if( !move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $content_dir . $name_file) )
    {
        die("Impossible to copy the file in $content_dir");
    }
    die("File uploaded successfully");
}

?><html>
<head>
        <title>file upload</title>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
        <input type="file" name="fichier">
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="HTML upload">
    </form>
    <button>AJAX Upload</button>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('button').on('click', function(e)
        {
            var data = new FormData()

            $.each( $('input[type=file]'), function(id, obj)
            {
                data.append( obj.name, obj.files[0] )
            })

            $.ajax({
                url: 'upload.php',
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                timeout: 300,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(msg)
                {
                    alert(msg)
                },
                error: function(xhr, str)
                {
                    console.log( xhr )
                    alert('Error : ' + str)
                }
            })
        })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Firebug raises an "aborted" error, while jQuery raise a "timeout" error.

I found no error in the apache log.

I removed all .htaccess files.

The PHP configuration, according to phpinfo(), is :

- file_uploads On
- max_file_uploads 20
- upload_max_filesize 200M
- post_max_size 300M

How could I make the AJAX way to work properly ?
Any help or guidance gratefully received.

**Edit :**

I finally found a way to make it work :

- First, the jQuery.each() callback function doesn't seem to return a dom object, but a jQuery object.
- Secondly, the parameter 'timeout' from jQuery.ajax was set in '300' (not present in my example, but in the code in production). In fact, this value is in milliseconds, not in seconds.

Here is my new code :

```
$('button').on('click', function(e)
{
    var myfile = $('input[type=file]').get(0).files[0]
    var data = new FormData()
    data.append( 'myfile', myfile )

    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        timeout: 30000,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(msg)
        {
            alert(msg)
        },
        error: function(xhr, str)
        {
            console.log( xhr )
            alert('Error : ' + str)
        }
    })
})
```